# React Lifting State Up - Why not call constructor of child when parent rerender?

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I am new to React. I just look into the [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) document.

```
const scaleNames = {
  c: 'Celsius',
  f: 'Fahrenheit'
};

function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
  return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

function toFahrenheit(celsius) {
  return (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
}

function tryConvert(temperature, convert) {
  const input = parseFloat(temperature);
  if (Number.isNaN(input)) {
    return '';
  }
  const output = convert(input);
  const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded.toString();
}

function BoilingVerdict(props) {
  if (props.celsius >= 100) {
    return <p>The water would boil.</p>;
  }
  return <p>The water would not boil.</p>;
}

class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.props.temperature;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
        <input value={temperature}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCelsiusChange = this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFahrenheitChange = this.handleFahrenheitChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: '', scale: 'c'};
  }

  handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }

  handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature});
  }

  render() {
    const scale = this.state.scale;
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
    const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          temperature={celsius}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="f"
          temperature={fahrenheit}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleFahrenheitChange} />
        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(celsius)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calculator />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I saw:
`Calculator` is the parent component, it calls `TemperatureInput` child in `render` function. At the first render of `Calculator` class, it calls the constructor of children. When the state of the parent change, the parent will rerender (of course), but in this time, the constructor of children was **NOT called**.

I confused about that. Could anyone help me? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The constructor will only be called the very first time a component is *created*.

If the component is re-rendering due to state/props updates, the constructor should not be called again as this would cause potential side-effects. If you had the following component:

```js
class Example extends React.Component  {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            example: true
        }
    }
}
```

If we changed `state.example` to false, and the constructor was called again, then our state would be reset so that `state.example` were equal to true again.

The constructor is only called once per-component, prior to the mount.

If the component is destroyed (due to not being part of the render tree any more - we navigate away from the page, for instance), then the constructor *will* be called again, the next time that component is rendered again for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
```If the component is destroyed (due to not being part of the render tree any more - we navigate away from the page, for instance), then the constructor will be called again,```
This is really the reason for my confusion. I try to show one child -> both children -> one child -> ... repeatedly. It actually calls the constructor of the child after removing a child from ```the render tree```. Thanks so much @AMcBride